# realloc fails on shrink

Tags: c, dynamic, realloc

Im not sure if im missing something here, but realloc() is failing with invalid size when i attempt to shrink a dynamic array of structs. ive trimmed the non-essential functions from the code to post:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char const file_name[] = "animals.dat";
typedef enum { 
    false, true } bool;
typedef struct {
    char month;
    char day;
    short year;
} date;
typedef struct {
    bool parvo_vacc;
    bool fip_vacc;
    bool rabies_vacc;
    bool has_mc;
    bool worm_vacc;
} md_history;
typedef struct {
    int id;
    char age;
    char name[25];
    char description[50];
    md_history medical;
    date intake_date;
    date adopt_date;
} animal;
void lookup(animal* list, int size);
int compare(const void* this, const void* that);
void sort(animal* list, int size);
//this brings the new name back with it, since it isnt saved correctly
//in the new animal
animal* add(char* name);
void del(animal* list, int size);
void print_results(animal** results, int size);
void print_animal(animal* print);
void swap(animal* this, animal* that);
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE* readfile = fopen(file_name, "r");
    if (readfile == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error file not found: %s\n", file_name);
    }
    //read data using fread(), keeping track of the number
    //of bytes missed
    int num_animals = 0;
    fread(&num_animals, sizeof(int), 1, readfile);
    animal* animal_list = (animal*) calloc(num_animals, sizeof(animal));
    int errnum = num_animals - (fread(animal_list, 
        sizeof(animal), num_animals, readfile));
    if (errnum > 0)
    {
        printf("Read encountered %d errors", errnum);
    }
    fclose(readfile);
    char c;
    char* name = malloc(sizeof(char) * 25);
    //switch statements dont allow declarations for whatever reason
    int x;
    while(c != 'q')
    {
        printf("Options: (l)ookup (s)ort (a)dd (d)elete (p)rint (q)uit (e)dit\n");
        scanf(" %c", &c);
        switch (c)
        {
            case 'l':
            lookup(animal_list, num_animals);
            break;
            case 's':
            sort(animal_list, num_animals);
            break;
            case 'p':
            for (x = 0; x < num_animals; x++)
            {
                print_animal(&animal_list[x]);
            }
            break;
            case 'a':
            //after dealing with lots of iostream errors trying to
            //set the name field in add(), i decided to just return
            //the new name to here and strcpy it
            animal_list = realloc(animal_list, sizeof(animal) * (num_animals + 1));
            swap(&animal_list[num_animals], add(name));
            strcpy(animal_list[num_animals].name, name);
            num_animals++;
            //memory leak here, since switch statements dont allow
            //declarations, i cant save the new animal pointer to a temp
            //var so it can be deleted
            break;
            case 'd':
            del(animal_list, num_animals);
            num_animals--;
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void swap(animal* this, animal* that)
{
    animal temp;
    temp.id = this->id;
    strcpy(temp.name, this->name);
    temp.age = this->age;
    strcpy(temp.description, this->description);
    temp.medical.fip_vacc = this->medical.fip_vacc;
    temp.medical.has_mc = this->medical.has_mc;
    temp.medical.parvo_vacc = this->medical.parvo_vacc;
    temp.medical.rabies_vacc = this->medical.rabies_vacc;
    temp.medical.worm_vacc = this->medical.worm_vacc;
    temp.intake_date.day = this->intake_date.day;
    temp.intake_date.month = this->intake_date.month;
    temp.intake_date.year = this->intake_date.year;
    temp.adopt_date.day = this->adopt_date.day;
    temp.adopt_date.month = this->adopt_date.month;
    temp.adopt_date.year = this->adopt_date.year;

    this->id = that->id;
    strcpy(this->name, that->name);
    this->age = that->age;
    strcpy(this->description, that->description);
    this->medical.fip_vacc = that->medical.fip_vacc;
    this->medical.has_mc = that->medical.has_mc;
    this->medical.parvo_vacc = that->medical.parvo_vacc;
    this->medical.rabies_vacc = that->medical.rabies_vacc;
    this->medical.worm_vacc = that->medical.worm_vacc;
    this->intake_date.day = that->intake_date.day;
    this->intake_date.month = that->intake_date.month;
    this->intake_date.year = that->intake_date.year;
    this->adopt_date.day = that->adopt_date.day;
    this->adopt_date.month = that->adopt_date.month;
    this->adopt_date.year = that->adopt_date.year;

    that->id = temp.id;
    strcpy(that->name, temp.name);
    that->age = temp.age;
    strcpy(that->description, temp.description);
    that->medical.fip_vacc = temp.medical.fip_vacc;
    that->medical.has_mc = temp.medical.has_mc;
    that->medical.parvo_vacc = temp.medical.parvo_vacc;
    that->medical.rabies_vacc = temp.medical.rabies_vacc;
    that->medical.worm_vacc = temp.medical.worm_vacc;
    that->intake_date.day = temp.intake_date.day;
    that->intake_date.month = temp.intake_date.month;
    that->intake_date.year = temp.intake_date.year;
    that->adopt_date.day = temp.adopt_date.day;
    that->adopt_date.month = temp.adopt_date.month;
    that->adopt_date.year = temp.adopt_date.year;
}

void del(animal* list, int size)
{
    printf("Delete by: (n)ame (i)d\n");
    char c;
    while (getchar() != '\n');
    scanf("%c", &c);
    animal* to_delete = NULL;
    if (c == 'n')
    {
        printf("Enter name to delete: ");
        char to_search[25];
        while (getchar() != '\n');
        scanf(" %s", to_search);
        int x;
        for (x = 0; x < size; x++)
        {
            if (strcmp(to_search, list[x].name) == 0)
            {
                to_delete = &list[x];
            }
        }
    }
    if (c == 'i')
    {
        printf("Enter ID to delete: ");
        int to_search;
        while (getchar() != '\n');
        scanf("%d", &to_search);
        int x;
        for (x = 0; x < size; x++)
        {
            if (to_search == list[x].id)
            {
                to_delete = &list[x];
            }
        }
    }
    swap(to_delete, &list[size);
    list = realloc(list, sizeof(animal) * (size - 1)); //fails right here
}
```

am i shrinking the array incorrectly? im pretty stumped here

EDIT: I know realloc() fails because it does so spectacularly and aborts, giving this message:

```
*** Error in `./final': realloc(): invalid next size: 0x0000000000c11250 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x77725)[0x7f6ae72ba725]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x82bfa)[0x7f6ae72c5bfa]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x85179)[0x7f6ae72c8179]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(realloc+0x22f)[0x7f6ae72c6e6f]
./final[0x401d3e]
./final[0x400b82]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7f6ae7263830]
./final[0x400849]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00403000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3146140                            /home/destrovel/cppwork/final
00602000-00603000 r--p 00002000 08:01 3146140                            /home/destrovel/cppwork/final
00603000-00604000 rw-p 00003000 08:01 3146140                            /home/destrovel/cppwork/final
00c10000-00c31000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f6ae0000000-7f6ae0021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f6ae0021000-7f6ae4000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f6ae702d000-7f6ae7043000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1069105                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f6ae7043000-7f6ae7242000 ---p 00016000 08:01 1069105                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f6ae7242000-7f6ae7243000 rw-p 00015000 08:01 1069105                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f6ae7243000-7f6ae7403000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1049974                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f6ae7403000-7f6ae7602000 ---p 001c0000 08:01 1049974                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f6ae7602000-7f6ae7606000 r--p 001bf000 08:01 1049974                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f6ae7606000-7f6ae7608000 rw-p 001c3000 08:01 1049974                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f6ae7608000-7f6ae760c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f6ae760c000-7f6ae7632000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1049970                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f6ae77f9000-7f6ae77fc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f6ae782e000-7f6ae7831000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f6ae7831000-7f6ae7832000 r--p 00025000 08:01 1049970                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f6ae7832000-7f6ae7833000 rw-p 00026000 08:01 1049970                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f6ae7833000-7f6ae7834000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffd8a23b000-7ffd8a25c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffd8a331000-7ffd8a333000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffd8a333000-7ffd8a335000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I rewrote the function to pass the list back to the calling function, as suggested by 2501, but it didnt change the program aborting at that same spot

Also, gdb gives this when evaluating that line:

```
realloc: Assertion `ptr == alloc_last_block' failed!
```

EDIT 2 : after a bunch of debugging, its the swap() that corrupts the heap, but i cant figure out why. i rewrote swap() as suggested, but a realloc() immediately after fails while a realloc() immediately before does not

Comment: Have you checked to see what size you are passing to `realloc` when it fails?

Comment: How did you determine `realloc()` failed?  Returning `NULL` does _not_ certainly mean it failed.  `realloc()` can return `NULL` on a 0 allocation as well as out-of-memory,

Comment: you shouldn't call realloc this way.  you are overwriting list when realloc fails, and you've lost the original pointer.

Comment: `swap(animal* this, animal* that)` is quite long.  Could simply use `void swap(animal* this, animal* that) { animal tmp = *this; *this = *that; *that = tmp; }`.

Comment: `scanf(" %s", to_search);` is as bad as `gets(to_search)`.  Use `scanf("%24s", to_search);`  Have any 25 letter names? IOWs, post your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. `swap(to_delete, &list[size])`

just needed to be `swap(to_delete, &list[size - 1])`

Hurray for stupid mistakes

Answer (score 2):

Variables are passed by value in C.

The pointer `list` passed to function `del` is changed by realloc in the function, but the pointer outside the function isn't changed. The caused undefined behavior.

Pointer `animal_list`, is passed here:

```
del(animal_list, num_animals);
```

the copy of that pointer `list`, is changed here:

```
list = realloc(list, sizeof(animal) * (size - 1));
```

The original pointer `animal_list` remains unchanged.

To solve this return the value of the new pointer list.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that you set yourself up for a memory leak by not using a `tmp` variable to assign the return of `realloc` before validating success. If `realloc` fails, it returns `NULL` and you have lost the ability to `free` the block of memory originally pointed to by `list`.